# Can I stub methods called through reflection using Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, reflection, mockito

I'm trying to write unit tests for my code that uses reflection to call hidden methods on an object I want to stub for my test:

```
methodUnderTest(Arg argument) {
  Method toCall = Arg.class.getMethod("toCall");
  Object val = toCall.invoke(argument);
  // Do stuff with val...
}
```

Is it possible to create a mock Arg that I can pass in to this method that will let me stub the toCall() call?

Arg is not an object I'm creating, so I can't change the accessibility of its methods.

Comment: If you change `Arg.class` to `argument.getClass()` then you can pass in a mocked `Arg` with a stubbed `getClass()` which returns a mocked `Class` with a stubbed `getMethod` etc etc. Reflection is a testability nightmare

Comment: Dang, Mockito can't mock Class. Says it is unable to mock final classes.

Comment: But if you change `Arg.class` to `argument.getClass()` as Colin suggested, you can stub `getClass` to return an inner class of your test class, that has a `toCall` method.

Answer (score 0):

yes, u can stub methods invoked with reflection. but you can't stub private method - mockito just doesn't have syntax for it. also you can't stub final methods, static methods, fields nor classes. for such hacking you will need powermockito.

but you shouldn't use it. refactor! split `methodUnderTest` into two (or three) methods. the most important one will get `Object val` as an input and will do your business logic. you have to test that method.

second method will prepare method and parameters to call (and eventually invoke it). currently in this part you access static field. don't. whenever possible use different ways (as suggested by Colin). if there is some complex logic then test that logic, but you don't have test `invoke` method - it works, guys from sun/oracle already tested it